# How to convert array of enum to array of int's

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Core Data and one of my predicates retrieves data based on the following enum:

```
enum Period : Int {
   Daily
   Weekly
   Monthly
}
```

My predicates is like this:

```
public static func byTypePredicate(periods: [Int]) -> NSPredicate {
    return NSPredicate(format: "period IN %@", periods)
}
```

My problem is I don't want to use `Int's` when calling this predicate, I want to pass the `Period` enum, but inside the predicate is have to convert it to `Int` to make it work.

Is there a quick way to convert it ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `periods.rawValue`?

Comment: Side note: As of Swift 3, the convention is to start enumeration cases with a lowercase letter: `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `map()` method (of the `Sequence` protocol) to map each enumeration to its integer raw value:

```
func byTypePredicate(periods: [Period]) -> NSPredicate {
    let intPeriods = periods.map { $0.rawValue } // [Int]
    return NSPredicate(format: "period IN %@", intPeriods)
}
```

Comment: That's so elegant. I like it.